# ERROR the property or indexer cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ProjectBase.Utils;

namespace EnterpriseSample.Core.Domain
{
    public class Notifikasi : DomainObject<string>, IHasAssignedId<string>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdateBy { get; set; }

        public void SetAssignedIdTo(string assignedId)
        {
            Check.Require(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assignedId), "assignedId may not be null or empty");

            // As an alternative to Check.Require, which throws an exception, the 
            // Validation Application Block could be used to validate the following
            Check.Require(assignedId.Trim().Length == 5, "assignedId must be exactly 5 characters");

            ID = assignedId.Trim().ToUpper();
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (GetType().FullName + "|" +
                    ID + "|" +
                    Name).GetHashCode();

        }
    }
}
```

I use the Notifikasi Class in a different class, but `oNoti.ID = "12";` generates an error:

> The property or indexer cannot be used in this context because the set
>   accessor is inaccessible.

Can anybody help me solve this? (I use an ORM if that's relevant).

```
INotifikasiDao dao = DaoFactory.GetNotifikasiDao();

dao.closeSession();
dao.openSession();
EnterpriseSample.Core.Domain.Notifikasi oNoti = new EnterpriseSample.Core.Domain.Notifikasi();
int no = 1;
oNoti.Name = "ETL Account History";
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today;
DateTime expiryDate = startDate.AddDays(30);
oNoti.StartDate = startDate;
oNoti.EndDate = expiryDate;
oNoti.Description = "ACC_HIST" + startDate + "Failure";
oNoti.ID = "12"; //this is where the error happens

dao.Update(oNoti);
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `ID`, please?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper my ID is Identity so i dont need declaration

see my code 
ID = assignedId.Trim().ToUpper();

Comment: `ID` is an identifier in your code, so of course it needs/has a declaration somewhere. Only if we can see the declaration, we can see why the compiler doesn't want to let you write into the `ID` property.

Comment: maybe ID declare like this `public int ID{ get; private set; }`

Comment: I also bumped into this kind of problem. I have "JOIN" where I finally select a new entity. And I need this "protected set" field as well... Have no idea how to overcome this.

Answer (score 12):

Your question is missing the important definition of `DomainObject`, but the error message indicates that the property `ID` is declared like this:

```
public string ID
{
    get;
    protected set;
}
```

This means that the value of `ID` can be read by anyone, but it can only be set from inside instances of `DomainObject` and derived classes.

Using `SetAssignedIdTo` isn't an option either, because it requires 5 characters, the ID you want to assign is only two characters long. I assume this method exists to be able to manually assign IDs to rows in a table that normally has an auto-incrementing key. Forcing 5 characters for this ID makes sure - to a certain degree - that the manually assigned keys won't conflict with the automatic created ones.

Comment: Or via the `public void SetAssignedIdTo(string assignedId)` method, by the look of it.

Comment: @Rawling: That's correct, but that wouldn't improve things. On the contrary, you are just circumventing "fail fast" with this, because now you have a runtime exception instead of a compile time error...

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this error when checking for equality in an if-condition like this:

`if (e.ChangeType = ChangeType.Update) {
...
}`

Mind the single equals in the condition (I guess I've been doing too much SQL lately haha). The error probably appeared because I was unwillingly doing an assignment to a member with read-only access. After adding another equals sign, everything was fine.