# How do i Solve this Compiler Error in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a Webshop and suddenly this error appeared,I tried many methods but the error still persists , can someone suggest what code changes i need to make in order to solve this compiler error, I am using Visual Studio 2019 and the code is from an earlier verison of Visual Studio.

#### Here is the Code of ManageProducts.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Webshop3.Models;

namespace Webshop3.Pages.Management
{
    public partial class ManageProducts : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            protected set;
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetImages();

                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                    FillPage(id);
                }


            }


        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
            Product product = CreateProduct();

            //testojme nese url ka parameter id
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {

                // ID existon -> update rreshtin ekzistes
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                lblResult.Text = productModel.UpdateProduct(id, product);
            }

            else
            {
                // nese nuk ekziston ID , krijo rresht te ri
                lblResult.Text = productModel.InsertProduct(product);
            }






        }

        private void FillPage(int id)
        {
            //Marim produktin e selektuar nga databaza
            ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
            var product = productModel.GetProduct(id);


            //Mbushim textboxat
            txtDescription.Text = product.Description;
            txtName.Text = product.Name;
            txtPrice.Text = product.Price.ToString();


            ddlImage.SelectedValue = product.Image;
            ddlType.SelectedValue = product.TypeId.ToString();




        }

        private void GetImages()
        {
            try
            {
                // Marim Images te Dropdown
                string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"));

                // Vendoj FileName ne arraylist

                ArrayList imageList = new ArrayList();
                foreach (string image in images)
                {
                    string imageName = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
                    imageList.Add(imageName);
                }

                ddlImage.DataSource = imageList;
                ddlImage.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddlImage.DataBind();

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                lblResult.Text = e.ToString();
            }

        }

        private Product CreateProduct()
        {
            var product = new Product();
            product.Name = txtName.Text;
            product.Price = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);
            product.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);
            product.Description = txtDescription.Text;

            product.Image = ddlImage.SelectedValue;

            return product;

        }


    }
}
```

#### Here is the Code of Product.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Webshop3.Models;

namespace Webshop3.Pages
{
    public partial class Product : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string Price { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public string Image { get; private set; }
        public int TypeId { get; internal set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillPage();
        }

        private void FillPage()
        {
            // marim te dhenat e produktit te selektuar
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
                var product = productModel.GetProduct(id);

                // Mbushet faqja me data
                lblPrice.Text = "Price per unit: <br/>$" + product.Price;
                lblTitle.Text = product.Name;
                lblDescription.Text = product.Description;
                lblItemNr.Text = id.ToString();
                imgProduct.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Products/" + product.Image;

                // Mbushe dropdownList me numrat 1-20
                int[] amount = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToArray();
                ddlAmount.DataSource = amount;
                ddlAmount.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddlAmount.DataBind();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

#### Here is the Compiler Error

[Compiler Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygbN6.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/14455248/1260204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setters for the Product class is private, so you won't be able to set a value from another class. You would have to make the setters public. Change

```
public string Price { get; private set; }
public string Name { get; private set; }
public string Description { get; private set; }
public string Image { get; private set; }
```

to

```
public string Price { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Image { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the previous errors now this new error appeared https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7YpX.png

Comment: Try using int.Parse(txtPrice.Text)

Comment: public string Price { get; private set; } , your property is of type string, change is to  public int Price { get; private set; }

Comment: Glad it worked. Can you also please mark my answer as correct

Comment: You should also probably make your price of type double, int is used for numbers without a fractional component, and you probably will have prices that would include cents

Comment: In the database i have specified price as int

Comment: I suggest you change it, otherwise, you can only have 'whole' number prices, for example, $10 or $20 and you won't be able to have prices like $10.21 or $20.50

Answer (score 1):

To be able to set properties like that, you'll need to make the accessors in the Product class public:

```
public partial class Product : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your properties should be public in the Product class as like below  ,

```
Public class Product 
{
public string Price { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added properties like:

```
public string Description { get; private set; }
                                 ^^^^^^^
```

this means that you can access (get) their values publicly but you can only set them within the class. just remove the `private` to be able to publicly set them:

```
public string Description { get; set; }
```